# access another computer in the same LAN of my laptop's router

Tags: networking, router, lan, subnet

I have below **A B C** devices in a work LAN, but no permission of the office switch.

[image]

in the office LAN:
**A**.a router (I want to expand a physical net port and it's what I happen to have at hand)
**B**.friend's computer (which provides some file and web services inside the office)

in my router's LAN:
**C**.my laptop
and maybe more mobile devices later

Is there a way for laptop **C** to access computer **B** ?
Computer B to laptop C is otherwise not important.

Similar questions must be asked somewhere but I'm poor at summerizing keywords... Any link or ref would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the both router how the subnets are connected:

- the router 192.168.1.1 should send data for 192.168.2.x over the router 192.168.1.100
- the router 192.168.2.1 should send data for 192.168.1.x over 192.168.1.100, it should do this without special configuration if the subnet mask is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks @user3767013 for your clarification. Silly me not even gave 1.101 a ping ..._(:3」∠)_ ....The router and the 1.101 computer are under the same subnet so 2.x devices could connect to 1.101 with no effort (though not inversely). Thanks again.